# Angular HTTP Empty Return

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio, iis-express

I have a pretty basic Angular Controller:

```
function PirateController($scope, $http) {
    $scope.DetermineBooty = function () {
        $scope.Processing = true;
        $scope.SavedCount = $scope.PirateCount;
        $scope.PirateCount = 'Please wait for Booty...';
        $http.get('http://www.Suamere.com/Apps/SCA/API/Booty/' + $scope.SavedCount).
            success(function (data) {
                if (data != '"0"') {
                    $scope.ResultText = $scope.SavedCount + ' Pirates found a minimum of ' + data + ' coins.';
                    $scope.PirateCount = $scope.SavedCount;
                } else {
                    $scope.ResultText = $scope.SavedCount + ' - There is no reason to calculate with that value.';
                    $scope.PirateCount = "";
                }
                $scope.Processing = false;
            }).
            error(function (data) {
                $scope.ResultText = $scope.SavedCount + ' - There is no reason to calculate with that value.';
                $scope.PirateCount = "";
                $scope.Processing = false;
        });
    };
}
```

When I publish this to my website, the Error never hits, and that's good.  Also, the Success hits and process correctly every time, and that's good.

But when I'm running this on my localhost in VS2013, the error always hits.  And the data is always empty.

However, in Fiddler, the result appears to be comming back correctly either on my website or on my localhost.  So why, only in my VS2013, is Angular catching empty when the HTTP Return obviously has something in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using an absolute URL as shown then when you run on localhost you are making a cross domain request.

Use relative URL's or set the domain using a variable

Comment: That sounds like what I'm looking for.  I cannot use relative, so how do I set it with a variable?  Do you mean create a string variable and pass it in exactly as it looks right now?  Does that really change how it performs cross domain requests?